I want to use camara project's api in my application but didn't understand how to implement their 3 legged authentication part
There are multiple type of camara api like sim swap and device status etc. but i didn't understand how to consume these api's. the documentation is not so helpful for me. So please if anyone can help me to understand this part.
i have tried to read the documentation and try to find related material but this didn't do much help to me. so if anyone can help me to integrate these api to my application.

You can get started with Vonage's CAMARA APIs https://developer.vonage.com/en/getting-started-network/concepts/network-apis
With a sandbox account you can get started within a few minutes (you can add your own number phone and do any sort of POC with Number Verification, Sim Swap, Device Location...) https://developer.vonage.com/en/getting-started-network/concepts/sandbox?source=getting-started-network

If you're struggling with 3 legged authentication process, we have detailed guides for that as well. https://developer.vonage.com/en/getting-started-network/guides/server-authentication?source=device-location-verification
